# Error al tratar de poner un componente en una pagina nueva

Tags: reactjs

me sale el siguiente error: ./src/pages/user/inicio.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../components/navbar' in 'C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\Proyecto-de-asignatura-\src\pages\user'

cuando trato de poner este componente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en esta nueva pagina:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta en la estructura de mi proyecto 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando necesites agregar código a una pregunta, por favor cópialo y pégalo en vez de poner un pantallazo. Así les facilitas el trabajo a quienes te pudiesen ayudar (entre otros beneficios). Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Según tu estructura de carpetas creo que la carpeta "components" se encuetra a un nivel superior.

```
import {Navbar} from "../../components/navbar"
```

Si puedes poner unas capturas de tu estructura de carpetas te podría ayudar un poco mas.

Saludos

Comment: edite la pregunta colocando la estructura del proyecto, muchas gracias espero me puedas ayudar

Comment: Hola, Según veo la estructura de tus carpetas te falta subir un nivel. Probaste el import como puse en mi respuesta?

Comment: Ahora sale este error

Comment: ./src/pages/user/inicio.js
  Line 11:  'Navbar' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Perdon creo que en mi respuesta habia puesto NavBar en vez de Navbar. Ya la edite. Prueba y me comentas

Comment: Gracias amigo eso era, sos un crackk. Saludos